# Getting length of ParallelQuery collection

Tags: c#

Is there a way to get the length of a collection from this?

```
        ParallelQuery<string> Lines = File.ReadAllLines("Topics.txt").AsParallel<string>();
```

This has no length property. There is a count method but it takes a Func. If I don't pass a Func parameter, I could get all the properties in the collection, but how could I not pass one in?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`Count()` extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383959(v=VS.100).aspx) - but it will enumerate the entire collection.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to pass in a Func, use [ParallelEnumerable.Count](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383959(v=VS.100).aspx).